# Log in User (Craft 3)

Tags: plugin-development, craft3, users, login

How can I log in a user in Craft 3 and redirect to a url?

This doesn't work:

```
$username = $user->username;
$userCode = $user->teamCode;
Craft::$app->user->login($username, $userCode);
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Documentation for this can be found in [Craft's class reference](https://docs.craftcms.com/api/v3/craft-web-user.html#method-loginbyuserid).

```
# Login as user, by id
Craft::$app->getUser()->loginByUserId($user->id);

# Redirect
return Craft::$app->getResponse()->redirect($url)->send();
```

Or, if you're in a controller:

```
return $this->redirect($url);
```